# Concavity of a multiplicatively separable function

Tags: functions

Let $f(x,y) = g(x) h(y)$, where $g$ and $h$ both are concave and non-negative everywhere. Is $f$ also concave?

**What I've tried:**
Let $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
As $g$ is concave,
$$
g(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) x') \geq \lambda g(x) + (1 - \lambda) g(x')
$$
and $h$ is concave,
$$
h(\lambda y + (1 - \lambda) y') \geq \lambda h(y) + (1 - \lambda) h(y').
$$
Everything is non-negative, so we can safely multiply the two inequalities:
$$
g(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) x') \cdot h(\lambda y + (1 - \lambda) y')
\geq (\lambda g(x) + (1 - \lambda) g(x')) \cdot (\lambda h(y) + (1 - \lambda) h(y')).
$$
(The left-hand side is equal to $f(\lambda (x,y) + (1 - \lambda)(x',y'))$.
For $f$ to be concave, this should be at least $\lambda f(x,y) + (1 - \lambda) f(x',y')$.)

Expanding the right-hand side,
$$
\lambda^2 g(x) h(y) + \lambda (1 - \lambda) (g(x) h(y') + g(x') h(y)) + (1 - \lambda)^2 g(x') h(y').
$$
Rewrite using the definition of $f$:
$$
\lambda^2 f(x,y) + \lambda (1 - \lambda) (f(x,y') + f(x',y)) + (1 - \lambda)^2 f(x',y').
$$
Can we argue that this is at least $\lambda f(x,y) + (1 - \lambda) f(x',y')$?